# Difference between the tags [negatives] and [negation]

Tags: discussion, tags

There are separate tags [[negatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negatives)] and [[negation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negation)].  What is the difference between these tags (or rather, is there any difference)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fail to see any difference; one question is even tagged with both. I would suggest that we merge them (under ["negation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_%28linguistics%29) rather than under "negatives", which makes me think of [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: Agreed; merge + synonym creation done.